# Authenticated File with google cloud storage

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-storage, user-permissions

Using the google cloud storage platform I didn't find anything speaking about adding permissions to files.

I would like to store files that are only available for my website users but not in public. Is there any way to achieve that? Google documentation is not so explicit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. You can modify the access controls on your objects and associate your website users with a group, see: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#About-Access-Control-Lists
2. You can create signed URLs for your users so that they don't need to have a Google account, see: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs

Comment: Thank you! Do you see any ways to automatically associate my website users with a group?

Comment: If your users don't have Google accounts, there's no easy way to create a link.  So the second solution (signed URLs) is more appropriate.